# What are SQLite triggers useful for?

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

What are SQLite triggers good for compared to (pre-compiled/macro-style) sequences of statements? Any useful optimization perhaps? Or just a matter of programmer taste?

I find triggers rather hard to use in several cases since Common Table Expressions such as SELECT won´t work in triggers. Maybe I´m looking at this the wrong way. Hence the generic question.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger runs when a thing happens.

Typically, you wouldn't be selecting anything in a trigger, because there's nowhere for the output result to go.  Rather, you'd be updating something else - for example, say you're building a family tree database, and you have a table for Individuals, as well as one for Families.

In that example, you might have a trigger such that when a record is inserted into the Individuals table, you might also create a record in the Families table if you don't already have an entry in Families for the LastName of the Individual.